# String aggregation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I new to oracle SQL.I want to get the output like this

```
    deptno         ename
    10               A
    20               b    
    30               c
    10               d
    10               e
    30               f
```

as

```
     deptno                 ename
       10                        a,d,e
       20                        b
       30                        c , f
```

in single select statement?

Comment: check out the `listagg()` function in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

```
select deptno, listagg (lower(ename),', ') within group (order by ename) ename from
(
select 10 deptno,'A' ename from dual union all
select 20 deptno,'b' ename from dual union all
select 30 deptno,'c' ename from dual union all
select 10 deptno,'d' ename from dual union all
select 10 deptno,'e' ename from dual union all
select 30 deptno,'f' ename from dual   
)
group by deptno
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want inside select query to be generic..could you pls help me

Comment: select deptno, listagg (lower(ename),', ') within group (order by ename) ename from %your_table%
group by deptno